# Ref vs No Ref for self-modifying objects

Tags: c#, parameters, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, ref

If the object being referenced as a parameter is being modified in a function, does it matter if you use ref or not?  Is there a difference between the following two functions?

```
void DisposeObject(ClassThing c)
{
   c.Dispose();
}

void DisposeObject(ref ClassThing c)
{
   c.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesnt depend in your case.

**BUT:**

if you pass a reference object with the ref keyword you have inside of the method the possibility to change the reference to point to another Object of this type (so it will be visible outside of the method)

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't matter. What matters is if you're assigning something to `c` (and want it reflected outside the method):

```
c = new ClassThing();
```

In that case you'd use [`ref`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: I guess I could reword the question to ask if ref changes anything when you are only calling functions on c that don't have a return value, but which do impact c itself.

Comment: It changes nothing. (sorry, that's what i meant when i said `it doesn't matter`)

Answer (score 0):

According to [the MSDN guide to passing reference-type parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6938f28.aspx):

> When you pass a reference-type parameter by value, it is possible to change the data pointed to by the reference, such as the value of a class member. However, you cannot change the value of the reference itself; that is, you cannot use the same reference to allocate memory for a new class and have it persist outside the block. To do that, pass the parameter using the ref or out keyword.

So you can alter the original object, but you cannot change the original object to reference a different location in memory. Example:

```
static void Main()
{
    int[] integerArray = new int[8];
    foo(integerArray);
}

private void foo(int[] myArray)
{
    myArray[0] = 5;  //this changes integerArray
    myArray = new int[4]; //this does not change integerArray,
                          // ... but it would if you used ref or out
}
```

So the difference does matter, although I don't know specifically about the behavior of `Dispose()`.